# How can I show a text in <video> tag, if source of the video is not defined

Tags: html, video, tags

On my html-page there is a  tag, created programmatically with JS.
Creation of the tag is made in 2 steps:

1. After step 1 in the DOM the next element appears:

```
<video autoplay="" style="width: 320px; height: 240px;">
<p>+++ Video inaccessible +++</p>
</video>
```

Now source of the video is not defined.

2. The video source is assigned (when the reference will be received from a remote peer by webRtc):

```
userAV.audio.srcObject = event.streams[0];
```

But this step may occur or not. 
My question is about the case then the reference will not be received.
The question is: how can I make a text instead of video to be appeared (for example - video inaccessible) between steps 1 and 2  ?

I have tried to do it as in step 1 - I have added

tag with a text (text node), but the text doesn't appear on the screen.
While I see that the region 320*240 is reserved for a video, but it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div id="video-container">
    <video style="width: 320px; height: 240px;" controls>
       <!-- No source defined -->
   </video>
      <div id="video-placeholder">
       Video is not available
       </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Jason K.C, thank you - I will try it. Therefore, the problem is - absence of surrounding div (video-container) ? Also, does it matter - in my code the tag 'p' was used, in your - only text without 'p' (simple textnode) ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).